# Python flask redirect with error

Tags: python, exception, web, flask

i want to redirect to signup page with error code when exception occurs. How can i do this in flask? How can i redirect to the same page with error code?

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET','POST'])
def signup():
  error = None
  if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
      ... my code ...
    except Exception, e:
      error = "hey this is error"
      ... i want to redirect to signup with error ...
      ... i get only some stacktrace page due to debug ...
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
  return render_template('signup.html', error=error)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to place try/except dependent return statements to handle that. The issue is that no matter what happens in the try/except it will always go to the login page if it enters the if statement. You'll need to break up your return statements accordingly.

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET','POST'])
def signup():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            ... my code ...
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        except Exception, e:
            error = "hey this is error"
            ... i want to redirect to signup with error ...
            return render_template('signup.html', error=error)
    return render_template('signup.html', error=error)
```